# Angular: how to show default selected in dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have below drop down. How can i show "C" as selected:

```
<select ng-model="sortData">
    <option value='abc'>A</option>
    <option value='xyz'>B</option>
    <option value='prq'>C</option>
    <option value='LMN'>D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What exactly you want?Do you need select an option to selected as default?
If yes you can use selected="selected" like below
     <option selected="selected" value='prq'>C</option>

Comment: try this sortData =  'prq'

Comment: I just added 'ng-selected="true"' it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set default value in scope

```
$sope.sortData = "prq";
```

Or

```
<select ng-model="sortData">
    <option value='abc'>A</option>
    <option value='xyz'>B</option>
    <option ng-selected="true" value='prq'>C</option>
    <option value='LMN'>D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

here is one more way to do it:

```
<select ng-model="sortData" ng-init="sortData='prq'">
  <option value='abc'>A</option>
  <option value='xyz'>B</option>
  <option value='prq'>C</option>
  <option value='LMN'>D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller define the $scope value

```
$scope.sortData = 'prq';
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show this as default value set

```
$scope.sortData = 'prq';
```

Comment: cant we set in view?

Comment: for this you have to make ng-select="true" for crossponding value

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this it will work...

```
<select ng-model="sortData">
   <option value='abc'>A</option>
   <option value='xyz'>B</option>
   <option value='prq' selected>C</option>
   <option value='LMN'>D</option>
</select>
```